# Copyin a Classes from other project into Xcode 4 project gives Undefined symbols error

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I am getting InfoViewControlelr.h .m .xib file from other project adding to existing project which I have in Xcode 4 but when I build the project it gives the following error

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InfoViewController", referenced from:
```

Comment: have u checked the copy items to destination folder?

Comment: try copying one by one and build after copying each one.if its also gives u error,then add  new file in your xcode and copy only the code from that other project

Comment: @alpz it shows Apple Mach-O Linker(Id)Error

Comment: Did you selected the Target at bottom while copying files?

Comment: how to add in xcode 4 the new UIViewController Class becuase it shows different spearate view separaet xib how to use them

Comment: @dh14-sl yes i have selected target

Comment: It seems u r missing some framework.Check all the frameworks that u have in your other project

Comment: @alpz it was just adding one by one and build

Answer (score 1):

You have to notify the compiler to compile your `InfoViewController` that you've added.
You can do this as following.
Please go to Project's TARGET and choose Build Phases tab.
And add your `InfoViewController.m` to Compile Sources section.

And last you can rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by either neglecting to select "add to target" when importing the file, or by a descrepensy between the frameworks you are importing and the frameworks that have actually been imported into the project.